# Java - Is it possible to read a serialized object without casting?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading objects from a serialized file and I really do not like the fact that I have to cast the result e.g.

```
vars = (HashMap<String, Integer>) out.readObject();
```

Being a fan of type information as  I loathe the cast. Is it possible to avoid it and tell explicitly what type should be read from a serialized file?

Comment: I thing there is no another method.

Comment: No.  Deal with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream` is not a generic type, and does not provide generic methods.

There are specific methods for `read[primitive]` provided, but for actual objects, only `readObject` is provided - which returns `Object`.

Of course, if you don't need to use Java's own `Serializable` or `Externalizable` interfaces and would rather serialize with specific frameworks (e.g. Jackson), you may avail of methods that do not require explicit downcasting upon de-serialization.

**Note**

`ObjectInputStream` is not `final`, and you can extend it to provide your own implementation, which could allow you to provide a generic class or method and prevent casting when invoking some `readTypedObject` method of your own.

You could then compare `readClassDescriptor()` with a `Class<T>` you initialized your own `ObjectInputStream` implementation with, in order to make sure the object that is being read can be assigned to your parametrized type.

However, you'd end up casting to `T` at some point anyway, since you probably don't want to override `readObject` too!

TL;DR, way too much effort and complication in my opinion, I'd just go with casting at the receiver end.

Comment: Tragically, OIS actually _does_ have generic methods such as `private final Object readObject(Class<?> type)`, but these are implementation-private.